# Get last captured image?

Tags: android, camera, imageview

I have an application, where you can take a picture about yourself (the app saves the image in a specified folder called "MyAppImage"), and I want to display the taken image in a second activity with a code, how to do this? I want to display it in a imageView in my SecondActivity, but I need a code that can get the last captured camera image from this folder, is there any way to do this?

Hope someone can guide me, how to do this, thanks!

Comment: Hey @Tin_Ram.....i have same Queries to set last captured images into View Pager......my Question link is.............http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42066564/view-pager-can-not-display-last-captured-images

Comment: Please tell me if you know....i can not fetch last captured Images in View pager...Please once refer my question..because its seem's there is No Error their...):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**After take photo:**

MainActivity

```
 String filePath;
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
        ...
        }

    private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

      String fileName = "yourPhotoName" + ".jpg"

      filePath =  "pathOfMyAppImageFolder" + fileName;

      File destination = new File(filePath);

    FileOutputStream fo;
          try {
           destination.createNewFile();
           fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
           fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
           fo.close();
          } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
         }
      }

      yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AnotherActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("filePath", filePath)
                startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
```

AnotherActivity

```
String filePath;
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = this.getIntent();

    filePath = intent.getStringExtra("filePath");

    File imgFile = new  File(filePath);

    if(imgFile.exists()){

        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

        ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);

        myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

        }
     }
```

**Take the last photo of the folder:**

```
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    List<File> files = getListFiles(new File("MyAppImageFolderPath")); 

    File imgFile = files.get(files.size());

    if(imgFile.exists()){

        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

        ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);

        myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

        }
     }



 private List<File> getListFiles(File parentDir) {
    ArrayList<File> inFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
    File[] files = parentDir.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            inFiles.addAll(getListFiles(file));
        } else {
            if(file.getName().endsWith(".jpg")){ //change to your image extension
                inFiles.add(file);
            }
        }
    }
    return inFiles;
}
```

Comment: Hey @Tin_Ram.....i have same Queries to set last captured images into View Pager......my Question link is.............http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42066564/view-pager-can-not-display-last-captured-images

Comment: Please tell me if you know....i can not fetch last captured Images in View pager...Please once refer my question..because its seem's there is No Error their...):

Answer (score 1):

Once you takePhoto, save it into file.
Then call intent to start second activity and putExtraString with your image file path.
That is all.

Comment: Hey @Tin_Ram.....i have same Queries to set last captured images into View Pager......my Question link is.............http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42066564/view-pager-can-not-display-last-captured-images

Comment: Please tell me if you know....i can not fetch last captured Images in View pager...Please once refer my question..because its seem's there is No Error their...):